# Dynamic sidebar title in category page(Wordpress/Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I got a sidebar on each category page and i want to make the title of the widget dynamic, to echo the category name. 
I consider adding on the sidebar function a php line to echo the page title.
The registered sidbar code:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar Shop Page', 'shop-isle' ),
    'id'            => 'shop-isle-sidebar-shop-archive',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => " php code goes here</h3>",

) );
```

I must admit i am noob when it comes to php, can you give me a hint or an ideea to create this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can add sidebar title without sidebar code by using customize.  

<h3 class="widget-title"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php
        if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('shop-isle') ) : ?><?php endif; 
    ?>.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my issue, i added your code into sidebar-shop.php file and it solved my problem. Thank you @Shital Marakana

Comment: welcome! happy to help you :)